# MVC ASPX Search box with multiple searching column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search-box

I have an existing table with many columns wherein I wanted to do a searchbox for the data inside the table.

I am using an ASPX page.
Can anyone give me an example so that I could at least refer my project there ?

Thanks.

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
           <%: Html.ActionLink("Employee", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm }) %>
        </th>
        <th>
             <%: Html.ActionLink("Department", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DeptSortParm }) %>
        </th>
        <th>
          <%: Html.ActionLink("Local", "Index") %>

        </th>
        <th>
          <%: Html.ActionLink("Position", "Index") %>

        </th>
        <th>
             <%: Html.ActionLink("DirectLine", "Index") %>
        </th>
        <th>
          <%: Html.ActionLink("Plant", "Index") %>
        </th>

    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <h6> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emp_Name) %></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
             <h6> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emp_Dept) %> </h6>
        </td>
        <td>
           <h5> <b><%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emp_Local) %></b></h5>
        </td>
        <td>
             <h6> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emp_Position) %> </h6>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h6> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emp_DirectLine) %>  </h6>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h6> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emp_Entity) %> </h6>
        </td>

    </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

and my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string nameString, string local, string dept )
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Phone Directory";
        List<PD_Employee> model = db.PD_Employee.ToList();


    } ....... This is what I'm gonna do.
```

I'll gonna give bounty for this after 2 days !

Comment: Can you show some code or example that what you want  ?

Comment: You want to search in PD_Employee by anyone of nameString or local or dept ?

Comment: Yes @MairajAhmad .. That's what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get data on basis of either `nameString`,`local` or `dept` than you have to use `or` condition in `linq`.

```
List<PD_Employee> model = db.PD_Employee.Where(x => (x.Name == nameString || x.Local == local || x.Dept = dept)).ToList();
```